# How to send SMS from mobile app using Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am trying to embed SMS feature in my Android app. So for this, I thought of using FCM and develop push notification, but it demanded the usage of an app server, hence decided not to pursue in that path.

A friend of mine suggested to use Twilio. So started to use since yesterday. I downloaded Java library and worked on it. Then realised that should not be used. While browsing through, fortunately, came across the below link:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html

Please can you clarify the below questions:

Where will I deploy backend project? In which Android folder do I need to deploy this? Do I need to take it as a complete project or take only the Java class?

The Android application is manageable and I can complete the work now.

Comment: I understood the overall working. I completed. But messages are leaving, but the messages are not received at the other end. Also no error messages are received. How can I check where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The back-end project needs to be deployed to a remote server, not as part of your Android application.

In the blog post you reference you build a Spark application which you can choose to deploy wherever you want. For your convenience there is a *Deploy to Heroku* button in the post, which you can use to automatically deploy the example application to [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for example.

Comment: Thanks PhilNash for your reply. I will close this thread as I have implemented push notification using fcm. Thanks and apologies for not closing this